# Finding the Documentation for Maven Jars

Tags: maven, jar

I was just wondering where I can find the documentation for jars you download in your pom.xml in maven. I don't see any obvious link to a PDF or anything on the maven site and there seem to be no real questions about this from my searching on the internet. So I feel like there is something pretty obvious I am missing. Is it assumed that Jars are self documenting/self-evident in their functions?

Comment: javadoc is the only standard documentation.  Most modern artifacts attach that.

Comment: Most modern IDEs decompile the .class files for reading purposes. Javadoc can be seen attached to every method and class signature in most of the libraries shipped these days

Comment: Oh sorry I'm pretty new with Maven (and projects of this size in general), didn't realize that its the same libraries as everywhere else and you just need to search them up. The contents just were itemized which anywhere on the maven site page which confused me.